# Parent node custom attribute could not be parsed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a container div which have a custom data attribute `data-gid` in it. While clicking on an element inside that div, I need to get the custom attributes of the parent div.

Html

```
     <div ng-repeat="(key, qn) in list >
     <div data-gid="{{ qn.id }}" >
        <div id="child1">
           <button ng-click="getParents($event);">Click</button>
         </div>
     <div>
    </div>
```

Js

```
$scope.getParents = function(evt){
  var elem = evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-gid');
  console.log(elem); 
}
```

The problem is I'm always getting the `data-gid` as `null`.
When I checked

```
console.log(evt.target.parentNode)
```

what I'm getting is

```
<div data-gid="" >
```

So what's the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

As `evt.target.parentNode` will point to `div#child1` and you need to find its parent, thus you need to use

```
evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-gid')
```

OR, **I would recommend** You can pass `qn.id` directly to the function

```
<button ng-click="getParents(qn.id);">Click</button>
```

Comment: methinks, second variant better :-)

Answer (score 1):

pass the gid parameter to the function

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, qn) in list >
 <div data-gid="{{ qn.id }}" >
    <div id="child1">
       <button ng-click="getParents(qn.id);">Click</button>
     </div>
 <div>
</div>




 $scope.getParents = function(gid){      
  console.log(gid); 
}
```